# Is there a way to transfer money from the gift card?

Tags: google-play-store, google-wallet

I tried to pay a Google Developer account (to publish App) with the gift card and wasn't accepted despite **being a payment to Google Play**. Were added R$100.00 (US$33,24) and own iPhone, only use for Google Books and movies. Is there any way to transfer the money or gift with app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

The [Google Play Gift Card TOS](https://play.google.com/about/card-terms.html) (US) includes the following which mentions that once a Gift Card is purchased it can only be spent within the Google Play store and cannot be transferred or refunded:

> **2. Limitations.** [...] The Gift Card is not redeemable for cash or other cards, is not reloadable or refundable, cannot be combined by you with other non-Google Play balances in your Google Wallet account, and cannot be resold, exchanged or transferred for value, except as required by law. [...]

For reference, Google maintains a list of [purchases eligible for Google Play balance](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6080850?hl=en&ref_topic=3421698) per country which includes country-specific TOS documents. It's also worth noting that a balance on a Google Play Gift Card is different than your [Google Wallet balance](https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/6081624?hl=en&rd=1).

Comment: Why can't I pay the developer account and that is a Google Play payment?

Comment: See the second link above. In the US, the only purchases eligible for payment using a gift card are "Apps, Books, Movies, Music, Music subscriptions, Newsstand, Newsstand subscriptions." I don't know why Google chose the restrictions it did.

Comment: @Mr.Buster I believe the purpose of gift card is for end-user, as with giving a gift for friends to use and buy things on Play Store, and it's not intended for development related in the first place.